# bash glob not behaving as expected (puts parent directory as a parameter)

Tags: bash, wildcards

i am trying to copy the source code for a project to another directory, but i don't want it to copy the .git directory (since its big and unnecessary for me) i tried it using this:

```
cp -r ~/source/!(.git) ~/destination
```

but it copied the parent directory of source instead (in this case the ~/ home directory) to the destination. i tried to replicate it using these commands and it seems to work without globbing:

```
user1@user1:~$ mkdir test
user1@user1:~$ mkdir test2
user1@user1:~$ mkdir test/orig
user1@user1:~$ touch test/file1
user1@user1:~$ touch test/orig/file2
user1@user1:~$ ls test
file1  orig
user1@user1:~$ ls test/orig
file2
user1@user1:~$ cp -r test/orig/. test2
user1@user1:~$ ls test2
file2
```

but once i try to omit the subdirectory with globbing it copies the parent as well:

```
user1@user1:~$ rm test2/*
user1@user1:~$ ls test2
user1@user1:~$ mkdir test/orig/.sub
user1@user1:~$ cp -r test/orig/!(.sub) test2
cp: will not create hard link 'test2/orig' to directory 'test2/.'
user1@user1:~$ ls test2
file1  file2
```

printing what's in the expanded expression shows it actually is translated to 3 terms one of which is the parent directory:

```
user1@user1:~$ echo test/orig/!(.sub)
test/orig/. test/orig/.. test/orig/file2
```

is this a bug in bash or am i not using the glob correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is the intended behavior, but it seems that it can be avoided by using the `GLOBIGNORE` variable to restrict those patterns:

```
$ echo test/orig/!(.sub)
test/orig/. test/orig/.. test/orig/file2
$ GLOBIGNORE='?(*/)@(.|..)*(/)'; echo test/orig/!(.sub)
test/orig/file2
```

Comment: Iirc just setting globinore to anything is enough to make bash ignore . and .. - you don't need that complicated expression

Comment: @muru I didn't know that, thanks for pointing it out. But I guess that would fail in some cases. E.g.:`GLOBIGNORE='foo'; echo !(.bar)/` prints `./` and `../` but `GLOBIGNORE='?(*/)@(.|..)*(/)'; echo !(.bar)/` doesn't.

Comment: i guess it is somewhat intended since `GLOBIGNORE` is there for a reason.... but setting it to that exact filter seems to do the trick, oddly enough even though the documentation states it should work, if `GLOBIGNORE` is set at all it should omit `.` and `..` but it doesn't for me